# Trouble Running Laravel WebSocket on Windows Server with IIS

Tags: laravel, iis, websocket

I'm facing challenges setting up a WebSocket for my Laravel application hosted on a Windows Server with IIS. During the development phase, I used the Laravel Ratchet WebSocket package and ran it using the php artisan websocket:init command.

Here are the details of my setup:

Laravel Application
Windows Server
IIS for web hosting

Problem:
I'm struggling to get the WebSocket server running in a production environment. While the Laravel application is hosted correctly and accessible on LAN-connected PCs, the real-time chat feature, dependent on WebSocket, isn't functioning as expected.

Application reference: https://www.webslesson.info/2022/09/real-time-laravel-ratchet-websocket-chat-application.html

Installed Supervisor but encountered issues.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#flask-with-socketio The WebSocket package requires compression to be disabled. Did you do that?

Comment: What problem did you actually encounter? What error occurred? Check the logs for any errors or warnings that might prevent the WebSocket server from running.

Comment: I am new to the deployment side, and I recently learned how to deploy a Laravel app through a tutorial. It demonstrated that I should specify the directory of the 'public' folder for the site and import rules from the .htaccess file. I have successfully implemented these steps.

However, I am currently facing a challenge with running WebSocket. When I run WebSockets through the terminal using 'php artisan websocket:init' on my server machine, it functions perfectly for the server machine only. I have been unable to find any comprehensive guide on the internet for this specific scenario.

Comment: That’s great. If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, you could post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept that.